# How to make a curved alling on Css bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

[Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewaaS.jpg)

I need to do around this tree with 6 logos, how i can do this?
How i can make curved alligment?

Ty so mutch all

Comment: What? Please provide relevant code and images

Comment: Ok I see, you want 6 circles in a curved alignment around the tree

Comment: Yep, i have no code, i trying to start this

Answer (score 0):

Please do give information. Adding a border radius to give a curved edge in CSS is as easy as `border-radius: 5px` depending on how curved you want it to be

Comment: I need something like this
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/342/937/original/Sem_t%C3%ADtulo.png

Answer (score 0):

This is hard! No idea how to make this responsive. But here is my quick attempt: Just used flexbox to get the balls in one horizontal line and then used position absolute and some percentage guesses to position the balls vertically.

Tighten up as needed but I would wait for another solution

```css
.tree-balls {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.tree-balls img {
  width: 100%;
}

.ball-container {
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.ball {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: teal;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5%
}

.ball:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 15%;
}

.ball:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 15%;
}

.ball:nth-of-type(even) {
  margin-bottom: 25%;
}

.ball:nth-of-type(3) {
  margin-bottom: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree-balls">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewaaS.jpg">
  <div class="ball-container">
    <span class="ball"></span>
    <span class="ball"></span>
    <span class="ball"></span>
    <span class="ball"></span>
    <span class="ball"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Np. Side note only bc you spelt it wrong twice it's "much" just in case you're not doing that on purpose ;)